# Problem in running Stanford assignment on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new learner of public sources of Stanford cs106a. I got sucked when run my assignment1. You can download it from here:

https://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspmcs106a/Assignment1.zip

I suppose to see the  image  on the following file after press run on Stanford menu and choose CollectNewspaperKarel code.

https://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspmcs106a/07-assignment-1-karel.pdf

But there is no any Karel or his world. I didn’t get any error. I am running eclipse 2018-9 and my JDK version is 11.0.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.3. I added the Stanford plugin as well. I do the following instruction for installing eclipse and the plugin:

https://web.stanford.edu/dept/cs_edu/eclipse/

How should I solve my problem to see Karel at result window after run assignment? 
P.S. My English isn't good actually!

Comment: Sorry I know my problem isn’t generic but I don’t have any other options. :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We unfortunately are not a homework service.  We can help with specific issues, so what are the errors you encountered while working on this?

Comment: There is not any error. The course is for 2008. I can’t see instructor and there is not any active forum. I think maybe someone can help me to understand what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

I also had a same problem with those files.

The Assignment1.zip file seems working with the Java 6 runtime only.
You can still run it by downloading the legacy Java 6 runtime here and install it.

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

Then you need to configure to use the runtime.

1. Preference -> Java -> Installed JREs
2. Click Search
3. Select /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk
4. Check it
5. Preference -> Java -> Compiler
6. Select 1.6

However, I actually found newer assignments files which work with the updated Java runtime.

https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106a/cs106a.1178/

If you follow the Eclipse link, there are instructions to setup it.

You can also find each assignment page links.
For example, find **Assignment 1: Karel the Robot** on the above page and follow the *assignment page* link below.

Find **Click here to redownload the starter code if you have already completed the Honor Code form.**
You can download CS106A-Assignment1.zip which works with the updated Java runtime.